# Can't get shipping methods from order in woocommerce extension but can in theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a woocommerce extension and have the following section of code in one of my classes.

```
$order = new WC_Order(159); 
$shipping_methods = $order->get_shipping_methods(); 
print_r($shipping_methods);
```

This is returning an empty array as seen here.

```
[24-Sep-2014 04:05:02 UTC] Array
(
)
```

If I place the exact same piece of code in my theme instead the array is populated as expected and returns the following

```
Array
(
[10] => Array
    (
        [name] => International Delivery
        [type] => shipping
        [item_meta] => Array
            (
                [method_id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => international_delivery
                    )

                [cost] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 175
                    )

            )

        [method_id] => international_delivery
        [cost] => 175
    )
)
```

I've tried debugging this but cannot for the life of me work out what I've missed. The same three lines of code work in the theme, but don't work in the plugin. Is there a global or other variable I've missed?

EDIT:

The order object I am creating is already a completed order and I am just querying the information from it. I'm not sure if this is a loading issue as suggested below.

Also when I var_dump `$order` it is showing me the order object. Is there any reason why the inherited methods from the `WC_Abstract_Order` would not work at this point?

WP_DEBUG is on and no errors or warnings are being produced.

Also to note, this is in a class that extends `WC_Email`.

EDIT 2:

I have tracked down where the `$order` object gets messed with in my trigger method for WC_Email.

Calling this filter `woocommerce_order_get_items` breaks the $order object.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', array( $this, 'check_items' ), 10, 2 );
```

This is my line of code that if I disable this, then I am able to get access to the `get_shipping_methods().`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the previous developer was iterating over the `$items` and unsetting lines items incorrectly. After much frustration I fixed the detection of the line_item vs shipping item and now the code is working.

This was then being passed on to all the filters for the `$order` object effectively removing all traces of the shipping information. Always check the code line for line. I did work out that 2 filters to change line items keep the object persistently across calls, which is why it was deleting the shipping info.

Comment: Sometimes dealing with other people's code makes your hair go gray.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have WP_DEBUG mode enabled? If so, I'd expect to see some fatal errors such as `get_shipping_methods()` does not exist or maybe "Call to a member function on a non-object", which would both leave `$order` undefined and thus empty when you `var_dump` it.

Plugins load before themes (see the [Action Hooks Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) ), so WooCommerce is fully loaded by the time your theme is called. It is possible that your plugin is running before WooCommerce is loaded.

I would try running your code on a later hook, such as `plugins_loaded` or the WooCommerce-specific, `woocommerce_loaded`.

Comment: WITH WP_DEBUG on I'm not getting any errors as you suggest. I am already var_dumping the $order and it is being created. I'm also following the standard for checking woocommerce before loading my plugin. I tried using woocommerce_loaded hook but that breaks the plugin.

Comment: I'm also already using plugins_loaded to init my plugin. What I also find interesting is that this is to get information on an order that is already completed. I'm just querying it.

Comment: Well I'm kind of at a loss then. If they weren't loaded yet, you'd see errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions anyway. This is why I am so confused.

Comment: I tested your code in one of my WooCommerce plugins and as long as the order has items that require shipping I see an array returned. If the order does not have shipped items then I get an empty array. Since you said you used the same code (and presumably the same order number) this just confuses me further. I'd try disabling other plugins and your theme to see if there any conflict, but yeah I'm stuck.

Comment: Dev environment so I've only got woocommerce + my plugin. Default 2014 theme. I'm wondering if this has anything to do with it being an email class which might suggest a loading issue.

Comment: Maybe? I've done a little with creating a new email but not much. However, if I recall I did have access to the $order variable.

Comment: I have access to the $order variable in the trigger method but any other method in the same class the $order method only contains the simple order details and I cannot query shipping methods or other details.